# Asynchronous loading image from web to gridview in Android

Tags: java, android, gridview

[image: GridView]

I want to load images Asynchronously from web to my Gridview in place of bubdub image without blocking the UI.

I want the app icons get loaded from web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use picaso library for that

use

write below line in your adapter

**Picasso.with(context).load("Your web Utl").into(imageView);**

this will not block ur ui

have a look at that http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 1):

add picasso library to your project and add this code to your Adapter's Getview method where you are trying to add set ImageResource.

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(imageUrl_some_static_link)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.image_name_in_your_case_bubdub).into(your_imageview)
```

Hope this helps cheers